# How many mV ripple in DC is okay for powering an ATTINY?

Tags: voltage-regulator, attiny, ripple

I need to power an attiny85 from an MC3306A, and in order to calculate the values for the circuit I need to know the ripple I desire, what ripple mV is alright for an attiny to happily chug along?

Answer (score 5):

Entirely up to the designer to verify.

According to Atmel's own official [knowledgebase article](http://atmel.force.com/support/articles/en_US/FAQ/Power-supply-noise-in-AVR-devices) on power supply noise for AVR devices:

> There is no specification for maximum allowable ripple. This will be application specific.

In fact from that same source, it goes on to say:

> For digital part of the device the noise is about 3% of supply voltage
>   and will most likely not cause any harm. Anyway, in noisy environment
>   it is recommended to enable the watchdog timer to avoid code freezing.
>
> From an analog perspective the noise can give poorer performance, like
>   introducing jitter in PWM and affecting the accuracy of the ADC.

That is likely as close as you will get to a definitive answer. For reference, 3% of 5V is about 150mVpp. That should be acceptable for the digital circuitry. For the internal ADC circuitry, lower levels of ripple would provide more accurate results.

---

Furthermore, it goes on to recommend reading of the following two documents. While neither go into any specific values for what sort of ripple is acceptable, they may prove useful reading.

- [AVR Hardware Design Considerations](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2521-AVR-Hardware-Design-Considerations_ApplicationNote_AVR042.pdf)
- [AVR EMC Considerations](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc1619.pdf)

Comment: I would also like to point out that I found that information within 2 minutes of entering "AVR supply ripple" into Google. Furthermore, simply typing "supply ripple" into the search box on the [Atmel website](http://atmel.com) also finds the same information in no time at all. Could people please learn to first do a cursory search on Google, device datasheets, and the manufacturer website...

Comment: To be fair, the linked (sort-of) answer is in an online forum. I don't think I've ever seen this issue addressed explicitly in a datasheet or official app note for a micro. A real answer would have to include the spectrum of the 'ripple'- at mains frequency the entire range of the power supply for a given clock frequency would be acceptable. At RF frequencies probably much less. Anyway, I would say 50-100mV p-p should be no problem though ADC performance might suffer a bit (so to speak), at the 100kHz frequency of a 3306**3**A (typo in the OP?)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Both of the linked documents are official Atmel publications, as is the knowledgebase article from which I have quoted the text. I've updated the link to the knowledgebase to make it more clear.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. The word 'ripple' does not appear in either of the documents, btw.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Granted they don't give any specific voltages or definitive specifications. They only go as far as to give the 3% figure quoted. For a 5V supply, 3% would be about 150mVpp ripple which "will most likely not cause harm" - all a bit hand-wavy.